# new Version of records show in All Listview

Tags: list-view

I have Objects DealSheet__c and Change_Log__c .
when I am  updating DealSheet__c record then one new record will be create in Change_log__c with the same name....

now my requirement is Suppose i am updating 3 times in the dealsheet then that updated 3rd record only need to display in change_Log__c record how could i do?
Thankss in advance..

My trigger Handler Codde is

```
public class DatasheetHistoryClass{

    public static void datasheetHistory(Listnewlist,List oldlist){

    list HistoryData= new List();

    For(Dealsheet__c deal : newlist){

    Change_Log__c hobject = new Change_Log__c();
     string s = '.';

        hobject.name =  deal.name ;

        //hobject.isMostRecent__c= true;   
        hobject.Amended_Version__c = deal.Amended_Version__c;
        hobject.Meter_Name__c= deal.Meter_Name__c;
        hobject.Amended_Verssion_Sent_To_CP__c=deal.Amended__c;
        hobject.Amended_Versions__c=deal.Amended_Version__c;
        hobject.Broker__c=deal.Broker__c;
       // hobject.Broker_s_Name__c=  deal.Broker_s_Name__c;
        hobject.Brokerage_Per_MMBTU__c=deal.Brokerage_Per_MMBTU__c;
        hobject.BU_Contract__c=deal.Focus_ID__c;
        hobject.Buy_Sell__c=deal.Buy_Sell__c;
        hobject.Confirmation_Email_Sent__c=deal.Confirmation_Email_Send__c;
        hobject.Counter_Party__c=deal.CounterParty_Name__c;
        hobject.CP_Address__c=deal.CP_Address__c;
        hobject.CP_Address_Line1__c=deal.CP_AddressLine1__c;
        hobject.CP_Address_Line2__c=deal.CP_Address_Line2__c;
        hobject.CP_Confirm_Email__c=deal.CP_Confirm_Email__c;
        hobject.Price__c= deal.Price__c;
        hobject.Fixed_Price__c=deal.Fixed_Price__c;
        hobject.CP_ZIP_Code__c=deal.CP_P_O_CODE__c;
        hobject.Create_Date__c=deal.Create_Date__c;
        hobject.End_Date__c=deal.End_Date__c;
        hobject.External_Comments__c=deal.Trader_Comments__c;
        hobject.Instrument__c=deal.Instrument__c;
        hobject.Internal_Comments__c=deal.Internal_comment__c;
        hobject.Internal_Trader__c=deal.Internal_Trader__c;
        hobject.Link_ID__c=deal.Link_ID__c;
        hobject.Price_Type__c=deal.Price_Type__c;
        hobject.PriceIndex__c=deal.PriceIndex__c;
        hobject.ReSend_Email__c=deal.ReSend_Email__c;
        hobject.Start_Date__c=deal.Start_Date__c;
        hobject.Strategy__c=deal.Strategy__c;
        hobject.Terms_Condition__c=deal.Terms_Condition__c;
        hobject.Total_Volume__c=deal.Total_Volume__c;
        hobject.Trade_Date__c=deal.Trade_Date__c;
        hobject.Tradebook__c=deal.Tradebook__c;
        hobject.Vlm_Day__c=deal.Vlm_Day__c;
        hobject.Tradebook__c=deal.Tradebook__c;
        hobject.NG_Pipe_Name__c=deal.NG_Pipe_Name__c;

        HistoryData.add(hobject);

}



    try{
 insert HistoryData;
   }

   catch(Exception e){


   } 

    }

}
```

Comment: I would think you need additional requirements.  Is there some window in which the 3 updates can occur?  Does it occur all within the same code invocation?  Is it just remaining on the same page?

Comment: how are you updating three times? Is it through workflow field update/updating field through trigger or user changes three times?

Comment: Ya 3 updates will done in same window of DealSheet..and those 3 records are ddisplaying in Change_Log__c object....but in change_Log__c Object i want to show only  3 record

Comment: In the edit page only I am updating 3 times...when i am updating then trigger fires and new record will create in Change_Log__c Object

Comment: User Changes 3 times

Answer (score 1):

Each DML event on `DealSheet__c` will invoke a trigger. If that trigger then writes a record to `ChangeLog__c`, you will get multiple records for each user transaction that causes the DML.  This is expected SFDC behavior.

Since you are doing the change log in a trigger, you don't really know when the user is done editing (drafts) from finalizing (publish).

Strategies for dealing with this are hard and won't be bullet proof. For example, you can post-process the changelogs and merge them together if they were created in the same session id for the same deal sheet id. This could be done via nightly job considered only `ChangeLogs` created more than 24 hours ago.